# Alguém pode me ajudar sou meio novo no assunto... BANCO DE DADOS

Tags: mysql

Estou criando um site de teste de perguntas...
tem 3 tipos de testes.
AMIZADES
NAMORADOS
CASADOS

cada teste tem 15 perguntas, como faço pra salvar o texto dessas perguntas no banco de dados e depois gerar um resultado de acertos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, a lógica seria criar uma tabela com as categorias que você citou, com ID, Categoria. outra de perguntas com: ID, Pergunta, FK do Tipo por fim outra tabela com: Alternativa, FK da pergunta e um STATUS para indicar se a alternativa é a correta.

o resto seria mais a aplicação quem iria fazer, claro que dependendo das suas regras de negócio pode ser mais complexo. caso queria salvar as respostas do pessoal ou criar um ranking, por exemplo.

Comment: Po man eu entendi sua lógica, só não consigo entender aonde eu vou salvar o texto das 15 perguntas entende???